# How can I detect if a user click a tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code!
///
from tkinter import *
import os
import pygame

```
os.system(‘clear’)


#Window Setup
root = Tk()
root.title(‘cottontail’)
root.geometry(‘800x600’)
frame = Frame(root)
title_screen = Label(root, text = “Choose your rabbits name!”)        
title_screen.pack()
name = Text(root, width=10 ,          height=3)
name.pack()
confirm_name = Button(root, text= “Conirm?”, width = 5, height=3)
```

root.mainloop()

///

My objective is to take the input the user puts in the text box to make a label in a pygame window with that name. I figured that a button would be an easy way to confirm the name and open the pygame screen. If this makes any sense to you it would really be appreciated if you could help me. Hope you have a good night!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some research would have easily found basic button-function binding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with tkinter as I'm a PyQt dev, but I can help with your question as the logic behind both of them are same.

You can make a function that is called by the button whenever its clicked, and then, inside that function definition, do whatever you want.

Here's the website that explains this in detail -
https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-get-the-input-from-tkinter-text-box/